Gensim CoherenceModel: ValueError: unable to interpret topic as either a list of tokens or a list of ids
I'm losing my mind! I've run into a problem getting Gensim CoherenceModel to work with my BERTopic model.
I get the error:

ValueError: unable to interpret topic as either a list of tokens or a list of ids

So I went back to basics and borrowed a code block generated by Co-Pilot:
from gensim.models import CoherenceModel
from gensim.corpora import Dictionary

# Sample data
topic_tokens = [['word1', 'word2', 'word3'], ['word4', 'word5', 'word6']]
tweet_tokens = [['this', 'is', 'a', 'tweet'], ['another', 'tweet', 'here']]

# Create a dictionary
dictionary = Dictionary(tweet_tokens)

# Print the dictionary to verify
print("Dictionary:", dictionary.token2id)

# Create the CoherenceModel
coherence_model = CoherenceModel(topics=topic_tokens, texts=tweet_tokens, dictionary=dictionary, coherence='u_mass')


This simple code block also gives the ValueError!!
I'm running gensim.version 4.3.3
Any ideas?
I've masked my file path, but here is the Traceback info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\....\venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3577, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-121-b30698468f3c>", line 15, in <module>
    coherence_model = CoherenceModel(topics=topic_tokens, texts=tweet_tokens, dictionary=dictionary, coherence='u_mass')
  File "C:\Users\....\venv\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\coherencemodel.py", line 214, in __init__
    self.topics = topics

  File "C:\Users\....\venv\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\coherencemodel.py", line 429, in topics
    topic_token_ids = self._ensure_elements_are_ids(topic)
  File "C:\Users\....\venv\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\coherencemodel.py", line 453, in _ensure_elements_are_ids
    raise ValueError('unable to interpret topic as either a list of tokens or a list of ids')

ValueError: unable to interpret topic as either a list of tokens or a list of ids


Can you expand your question to include the entire error message and traceback shown, somit's clear what exact lines and included code file triggers the error?
